# Limit on webgl objects in different browsers

Tags: web-applications, webgl

When opening an html file with 16 webgl objects in Chrome I get a warning that there are too many webgl objects. However with 15 objects this works fine. I haven't got this problem with Edge even with 20 objects. I was wondering what are the limits on the number of webgl objects for different browsers?

Answer (score 1):

It's not defined and even if you knew the limit today for a particular browser there's no guarantee it wouldn't change tomorrow.

The better question is what are you trying to do?

If you need lots of WebGL on the same page there are several solutions. The most performant is probably this one

Using raw-ish WebGL

[Multiple WebGL models on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541121/multiple-webgl-models-on-the-same-page/30546250#30546250)

Using three.js

[Is it possible to enable unbounded number of renderers in THREE.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608723/is-it-possible-to-enable-unbounded-number-of-renderers-in-three-js/30633132#30633132)

Comment: I have an R markdown document where I attach many WebGL objects. Basically I have a list in the document and the list length can be quite long.  I don't really know how much you can change the settings in this environment...