# Is it possible to change the canvas element of a WebGL context?

Tags: canvas, webgl

I have an application that currently is working with several webGL contexts that I need to make work correctly with only one webGL context (as many of the devices I'm targeting only support a single webGL context.)

I cannot reduce it down to a single canvas because I have layering with DOM-content such as webpages.

Ideally I would be able to simply switch the canvas and use the webGL context as normal, but I cannot find a method for doing this.  Any ideas?

I'm using Pixi.js v3 in case that is helpful, but I do not mind directly using webGL commands.  Is this even possible?  There was some discussion in 2012 on the Khronos mailing list about this but it seems to be a dead end (https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/archives/1210/msg00058.php) - but I'm hopeful there is an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Moving WebGL contexts to different canvases is not currently possible.

Does this technique not work for you?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30546250/128511

Comment: Sorry I forgot to respond to this, been a hectic past few months.  No unfortunately that technique does not work, as I need to be able to layer non-canvas content in between the canvas content.  This means I need to be able to draw some canvas content, draw DOM-stuff, and then in the same spot draw more canvas content, then more DOM-stuff, etc.  I wrote an optimizer that found optimal bounding rects for the canvas content and reduced as much of it to a single context as possible (since the layering order is known up front) which made it workable but not ideal.

Comment: maybe if you add a diagram of what you need to your question it would be clearer what you're trying to do