# WEBGL_shared_resources Extension in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

Im trying to use `WEBGL_shared_resources` Extension in chrome 58.
I checked if it supported with this code and I get error so its not.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width = "1250" height = "600"></canvas>

    var Canvas1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
    ctx1 = Canvas1.getContext("webgl");
    if(ctx1.getExtension("WEBGL_shared_resources") == null)
       throw "Shared resources are not supported";
```

My question is how do I add this extension?
Is that depend on browser version? OS? gpu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`WEBGL_shared_resources` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_shared_resources/) is just a draft and has never been implemented in any browser.

If you're looking for a way make it appear as though you have multiple canvases sharing resources see this q&a:

[Multiple WebGL models on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541121/multiple-webgl-models-on-the-same-page)