# Im getting an error, THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost, on the Android version of chrome

Tags: reactjs, three.js, jsx, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have made a personal website following a tutorial on YouTube, this is my GitHub repo https://github.com/tmich1997/resume

It is a `Vite+React` project and it has a bunch of 3D models. I deployed the website using `Firebase` and `Chrome` on a desktop, and it works exactly as intended however when I go to my mobile device (using an `s23+` and on Chrome) some of the 3D models are not rendering. Looking into the error it gave me:

- WARNING: Too many active `WebGL` contexts. The oldest context will be lost.
- THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.

Some BallCanvas elements won't render and the Computer from Computer.jsx won't render either. What can I do? I am really lost and a lot of the info out there seems to be purely JS rather than JSX solution.

I tried to follow this answer:
[Allowing more WebGL contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59140439/allowing-more-webgl-contexts)

In the `Ball.jsx` file I tried changing the scale:

```js
import React, { Suspense } from 'react'
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Decal, Float, OrbitControls, Preload, useTexture } from '@react-three/drei'
import CanvasLoader from '../Loader'

const Ball = (props) => {
  const [decal] = useTexture([props.imgURL])

  return (
    <Float speed={1.75} rorationIntensity={1} floatIntensity={2}>
      <ambientLight intensity={1}/>
      <directionalLight position={[0, 0, 0.05]}/>
      <mesh castShadow receiveShadow scale={2}>
        <icosahedronGeometry args={[1,1]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial
          color='#fff8eb'
          polygonOffset
          polygonOffsetFactor={-5}
          flatShading 
        />
        <Decal
          position={[0,0,1]}
          rotation={[2* Math.PI, 0, 6.25]}
          map={decal}
          flatShading
        />
      </mesh>
    </Float>
  )
}

const BallCanvas = ({icon}) => {
  return(
    <Canvas
      frameloop='demand'
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls 
          enableZoom={false}
        />
        <Ball imgURL={icon}/>
      </Suspense>
      <Preload all />
    </Canvas>
  )
}

export default BallCanvas
```

Comment: Hi, how many canvases do you use? Browsers have some maximum numbers of webGL canvases which you can have (about 10). If you have more it will call destroy on canvas and you will get this warning.

Comment: @VítZadina thank you for your reply. After some more Googling and research it turns out Chrome on android has a limitation of 8-webGL elements and I have a lot more. However, testing on Firefox mobile, Safari mobile (got a friend to check on her iPhone), and Edge mobile, they all render every webGL element present. It works perfectly on desktop.

Comment: is not good idea have lot of webGL canvases on page. Because it can be problematic on older computers and mobiles also. So it will work for you but on lot of devices it will freeze. We on our project just creating and destroying canvases on scroll change. https://mightyfossils.com/timescale/ you can check it here. Also for mobiles we must hide particles because it was performance problem.